# Swift/iOS - UITableView with UITableViewCell not populating results

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview

[image]Basically, i'm trying to get my TableView with SQLITE results but it is not popluating at all. The weird part is i edited an Example Project of sqlite to do the same, but from my database instead and it worked.

Also, in my project, which has the exact same code as the SQLITE example project, except the cell name and such, i can create an Alert to display one of the results from the array, and it works fine.

I don't get why it won't populate.

Sorry if i can't explain it well, but here's my code and an example of it trying to work with no TV results but with an alert.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return returnedCardNames.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:CardInfo_Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cardCell") as! CardInfo_Cell
    let card_name:CardInfo_Adapter = returnedCardNames.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! CardInfo_Adapter
    cell.card_nameLabel.text = "\(card_name.CardName)"
    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.getCardNames()
}

func getCardNames()
{
    returnedCardNames = NSMutableArray()
    returnedCardNames = Card_Adapter.getInstance().getAllSimilarCardNamesByUserEntry("null", passedSetName: "null")
    cardResults.reloadData()

    let card_name:CardInfo_Adapter = returnedCardNames.objectAtIndex(10) as! CardInfo_Adapter
    Util.invokeAlertMethod("Card Results", strBody: card_name.CardName, delegate: nil)
}
```

[image]

Comment: After trying multiple things, i used print("test1") to see if it's even running these method, and it seems they are not even being called. I'll try deleting the TableView and Cell and re-adding them onto the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by giving my UITableView the self methods for delegate and dataSource in ViewDidLoad().

```
self.cardResults.delegate = self
self.cardResults.dataSource = self
```

I used this other stackoverflow thread, which provided the answer.
[UITableView datasource functions not called (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685740/uitableview-datasource-functions-not-called-swift)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the libsqlite3 library then use this (it worked for me)

Create the database in your didload() function and then for your table view use this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell        

    var selectStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let selectSql = "select * from Inventory where ID = \((indexPath.row + 1))"
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(Database.database.sqliteDB, selectSql, -1, &selectStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK{
        if sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {

            let nameItem = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)
            let price = sqlite3_column_double(selectStatement, 2)
            let quantity = sqlite3_column_int(selectStatement, 3)

            let nameString = String(cString: nameItem!)
            let priceString = String(format: "%.1f",price)
            let quantityString = String(quantity)

            cell.itemName.text = nameString
            cell.itemPrice.text = priceString
            cell.itemQuantity.text = quantityString

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```